# Pass Entity Framework Core connection string in code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I specify what connection string EF Core should use in my code? NOT in any JSON or config file?

I have an SQL Server with many databases. All databases have the same login and are on the same server.

So, instead of saving a bunch of long strings, I'd rather have a "Server", "User" and "Password" property and get the database dynamically when needed and build a connection string from that.

However I couldn't find anything about EF Core that would allow me to specify a connection string in code, outside configuration files.

In the regular EF I saw someone point out that there is a base constructor for `DbContext` that takes a connection string but its missing from Core.

Answer (score 0):

THANK THE GODS!! That by sort of random luck I found out the nuget package
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

has extension methods, one of which is

```
public static void SetConnectionString([NotNullAttribute] this DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, [CanBeNullAttribute] string connectionString)
```

which is called like this:

```
DbContext.Database.SetConnectionString("bla bla");
```